# MySql returns wrong time from table data

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I have data in a table, and one of the columns is DATETIME.

```
select time from tbdt where unix_timestamp(time) > unix_timestamp(now()) order by time asc limit 1
```

now NodeJS prints wrong time in console.log() like,

actual datetime is `2018-12-16 15:00:00` in db table..
but mysql returns `2018-12-16T09:30:00.000Z`

which is 5 hours 30 minutes difference and my time zone is +5:30 (IST)

I don't exactly know where it goes wrong, either in MySql or in Node Js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `convert_tz` function in MySql.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+00:00','+5:30');
```

It has the following signature:

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 0):

You should check the server time on which your MySQL is running as it will pick the time from the server on which it is hosted.

This is being done by the MySQL, not by NodeJS and you can verify the same by directly running your above query into the database by console or SQL developer tool.